# How to enable JSON.NET serialization/deserialization tracing in asp.net owin api project?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, owin

I followed the JSON.NET [blog - enable tracing](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationTracing.htm).

It only shows how to enable tracing when you are using one of their object to manually deserialize. However, in asp.net OWIN, the serialization/deserialization is done by the framework and I wanted to know if there is any way to hook the tracing to asp.net OWIN stack for JSON.NET?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are doing webapi or mvc ?

Answer (score 1):

you can enable tracing like this

```
public class SimpleTracer : ITraceWriter
{
    public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, 
        Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
    {
        TraceRecord rec = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
        traceAction(rec);
        WriteTrace(rec);
    }

     //here you can write logic for json serialization/deserialization    
    protected void WriteTrace(TraceRecord rec)
    {
        var message = string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", 
            rec.Operator, rec.Operation, rec.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(message, rec.Category);
    }
}
```

plug in your tracing

```
 config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new SimpleTracer());
```

Based on : [Tracing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: "here you can write logic for json serialization/deserialization ", serialization and de-serialization is happening at the framework level. Web api controller I believe uses JSON.NET internally to (de)serialize JSON into .net objects. I'm not sure how do i trace "that" (de)serialization